# Differences between chemical bonds

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecules, binding-energy

Is there, from a physical point of view, an actual difference between the bonds used in chemistry: Covalent bond, Ionic bond, and Metal bond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as all the bonds are concerned, all of them share one common root cause, the electromagnetic interactions. Most of them either arise due to repulsion of proton-proton or electron-electron, or the attractions between the proton and the electron. It just differs in what context we are referring to in a particular case . This is also analogous to the difference between an ionic and a covalent bond, whereas a partial bond, which has both ionic and covalent nature.

Comment: Thank you, i.e. to be more precise: From a physical point of view, there is basically no difference. Only "boundary conditions" in their application/chemistry basically form these different bonds.

Comment: Doesn't the covalent and metallic bonds result from delocalization of electrons between orbitals rather than electromagnetic interaction?

Comment: Yes, so again, what is the reason behind the delocalisation?

Answer (score 4):

the differences have to do with the degrees of freedom available to the electrons taking part in the bonding interaction, which are described as being "shared" in the interaction.

In the case of a metallic bond, the shared electrons are in an energy level which is shared across all members of the bonded ensemble and we say the bonding electrons are *delocalized*- free to move anywhere they want. This makes metals electrically conductive. Since this sharing process is nondirectional, the bonded atoms are capable of slipping past one another, which makes metals ductile.

In the case of a covalent bond, the electron orbitals taking part in the sharing process are not spherically symmetric but instead stick out from the atom in well-defined directions. This gives rise to specific *bond angles* which resist being bent, and to shared electrons within the bond which are not free to wander. This makes covalently-bonded materials (generally) nonconductive and brittle.

In the case of ionic bonding, the charge distribution between the bonded atoms after one "gives" its electron to the other is strong enough that the net positive charge of one atom attracts the net negative charge of the other and the resulting solid is held together by coulomb forces.

This is a simplified picture; mixtures of these characteristics do exist and for example confer directionality to some metallic bonds.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just wonder how to see these principles as different. The ways to describe and to understand them are quite different(?) but are the underlying fundamental forces / principles actually different? I don't mean like "Finally, everything is energy" but do, e.g., metallic bonds and covalent bonds base on the same mechanics?

Comment: see roger vadim's answer below. -NN

Answer (score 2):

*Covalent bonds* arise when two atoms share electrons, when electron exchange leads to formation of bonding and antibonding orbitals. This is treated in many QM textbooks on the example of a hydrogen molecule, although much bigger systems, such as a silicon crystal, are held together by covalent bonds.

*Metallic bond* characterizes whole crystals of metals, where conduction electrons belong to the whole crystals. It can be shown that the Coulomb repulsion makes such a system unstable, even in presence of positively charged ions, and that the exchange interaction stabilizes it. Such an analysis is typically presented in textbooks on quantum statistical physics, e.g., Fetter&Walecka.

While it is fair to say that the two types of bonds are both electromagnetic in nature, and share the same key ingredients - such asthe exchange interaction - they describe two very different situations, require different mathematical approaches, and lead to qualitatively different results (insulator vs. metal).

*Ionic bonds* can be viewed as extremely polarized covalent bonds, to the extent that they are better described as attraction between charged particles, using a hydrogen-like model.

Finally, there are also other types of chemical bonds, such as *hydrogen bond* - ubiquitous in DNA and RNA.

Comment: Thanks, this highlights aspects I'm interested in. It's quite astonishing, that, though the electromagnetic force is the drive motor, the approaches, concepts and results are quite different. This is valid for a lot of other things, for sure.